# What algorithms are available to resize a hash table?

Tags: c, resize, hashtable

I have implemented my own hash table functions in C, but currently it doesn't support resizing. I was wondering what algorithms do exist apart from the brute-force way of creating a new empty hash table and moving everything there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is incremental resizing.

From Wikipedia:

> Incremental resizing
>
> Some hash table implementations,
>   notably in real-time systems, cannot
>   pay the price of enlarging the hash
>   table all at once, because it may
>   interrupt time-critical operations. If
>   one cannot avoid dynamic resizing, a
>   solution is to perform the resizing
>   gradually:
>
> During the resize, allocate the new
>   hash table, but keep the old table
>   unchanged.
>       In each lookup or delete operation, check both tables.
>       Perform insertion operations only in the new table.
>       At each insertion also move r elements from the old table to the new
>   table.
>       When all elements are removed from the old table, deallocate it.
>
> To ensure that the old table will be
>   completely copied over before the new
>   table itself needs to be enlarged, it
>   is necessary to increase the size of
>   the table by a factor of at least (r +
>   1)/r during the resizing.

So this is not some clever way of moving all of the elements from the old table into the new table (and if there is one, I haven't seen it); rather, it eases the burden of resizing by allowing the migration to happen gradually.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has some [words of wisdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable#Dynamic_resizing) on the subject.

Also, it's not a solution, but could be a part of one - if you're under windows you might use the VirtualAlloc family of functions which allow you to reserve address space without actually committing memory pages. That is, in laymans terms, you would do something like a "malloc" and tell it to "reserve 1000MB, but only make the first 10 available". So if you write past the 10MB, you'd get the usual crash. But when the time comes to expand, you just say "OK, give me another 10MB after the first ones". And the next 10MB is made available at the address directly after the first 10MB. It's like resizing an array. The actual RAM in use will be only as much as you need, but the memory addresses will be reserved in advance so that other memory allocation operations don't use them.

Comment: That's a pretty smart way to resize an array - if you have address space to burn (x64) - but it won't work for hashtables, you'd still have to rehash everything (and it is more complex doing that in place.)

Comment: @Eloff - Well, as I said - it's not a solution itself, just a part of one. And you don't have to reserve that much more address space. Just some reasonable amount. It's not a silver bullet, it just makes the resizing operation faster.

Comment: I see where you're going with this now, but it's dubious that it would actually make the resize faster. The major expense here is not memory allocation, that barely features. All the time goes into soft page faults to bring the new memory into the process address space (usually happens in your memory allocator when it zeroes the memory) and in the cost required to re-hash and re-insert all the elements in the hashtable. But for dynamic arrays, you don't need to copy anything, and you can pay the soft page faults one at a time (grow by one page at a time) now that's excellent!

Comment: I may be out to lunch about the minor faults, not sure. But regardless the cost of committing and zeroing the memory is the major part of the cost of allocating it.

Comment: @Eloff - Maybe. But if it's so, then I struggle to see any other possible applications for this feature of the Virtual Memory allocator.

Answer (score 1):

The usual cop-out is to leave it up to the client code to guess the best number of buckets up front.  That's serviceable, the client usually has a reasonable guess as to how many elements will end up in the table.  If you want to do it automatically then you first have to declare an array of primes for bucket sizes.  When you see the load factor of a bucket getting too high, pick the next prime in the array, recreate the bucket list and move the elements from the old buckets to the new table.